# MVC give authorization on login to access actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize

I've been running in circles trying to find an answer to this, and I can't seem to make any progress.

All I want to do, is check for a correct username and password combo, then GIVE the user authorization to access MVC actions decorated with the [Authorize] tag.

```
    public ActionResult DoLogin(PageInitModel model)
    {
        EF_db db = new EF_db();

        string saltPassword = getSaltedPasswordEncryption(model.UserName, model.Password);

        var user = (from s in db.Users
                    where s.Username == model.UserName
                    && s.Password == saltPassword
                    select s).FirstOrDefault();

        if(user == null)
        {
            model.LoginFail = true;
            return View("Login", model);
        }
        else
        {
            //
            // give the user some magical token to access [Authorize] actions here
            //
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Menu");
        }
    }
```

Above is the login action (called from a basic form), and below would be one of the actions I would like to restrict access to:

```
    public class MenuController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var pageInitModel = new PageInitModel();

            return View("Menu",pageInitModel);
        }
    }
```

I would like to keep track of the users myself (in my own tables), because there are many additional attributes I would like to track. I'm not sure if I need to write a custom AuthorizeAttribute, or what, but I can't seem to make any headway.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you going to log in users? FormsAuthentication using a cookie? You should probably look at existing membership providers before rolling your own. They all have easily customizable user profile fields you can use.

Comment: I think that's actually my question (not to sound snarky, I'm just new at this). By membership providers, do you mean Active Directory and things like that? Where would I look for info on that?

Comment: Yeah. Active Directory is for windows domain accounts. For separate web app accounts you should read up on SimpleMembership, ASP.NET Identity, or the old Forms Authentication. All of them have what you need right out of the box

Answer (score 1):

You should look into ASP.NET Identity.  Note this was introduced in ASP.NET 5 (?) and replaces some older frameworks Microsoft had like Basic Membership etc.

Honestly you really don't want to roll your own.  ASP.NET Identity does exactly what you describe right out of the box.  Keep in mind there are two distinct concepts Authentication and Authorization.

Authentication is verifying the user is who he says he is.
Authorization is restricting access to only users who are "allowed".

There are many ways to structure Authorization but I assume Role based Authorization will meet your need.  You will define multiple roles, say User, Admin, Moderator, Admin, etc.

You then restrict access to actions based on the role.  You can even make roles overlap and allow a single user to have multiple roles.  The end result is that once a user logs in their role determines what they can do via the authorize tags.

`[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`

If the user is not logged in, they will be redirected to the login form to AUTHENTICATE ("*Um I don't know who you are*".  Once authenticated if they are not authorized they will still be restricted from this action ("*Oh I know who you are but you are not allowed to do this*".

To round it out you can also have anonymous actions which mean no authentication is required and Authorize actions which are not limited to a specific role (any authenticated user is allowed but not unauthenticated users).

The fact that even with a basic [Authorize] you are having issues leads be to believe there is some configuration problems in even the Authentication. I recommend going through a tutorial building an example app like this one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx

Comment: Gerald, I did look into Identities, and it definitely seemed to be what I wanted. However, I could not manage to figure out _where_ the users and data were being stored. It seemed to be working purely on magic...I will definitely look into the link you provided.

Comment: @twsmale.  You can specify the Identity database however IIRC I believe by default is nothing is specified (i.e. no connecting string) then it will create a local SQL Express DB.  That is one of those Microsoft "we are going to help you out" by doing something you didn't ask instead of just saying "you need a connecting string stupid" which of course always ends up more confusing.

Comment: That was 100% my experience. It looks like the tutorial you send has info on specifying the DB, so I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you have your users information and you may want to use the authentication by custom code. But to actually login the user you must create a session of the user (Cookie session) for further authentication of requests.

You have already verified the username and password. now you've to create a session cookie using form authentication. Here's answer to your first problem:

> // give the user some magical token to access [Authorize] actions here

```
// User name and password matches
if (userValid)
    {

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

The `Authorize` attribute will then check if the request coming for the action is authenticated. This attribute internally checks if a session cookie is valid and authenticated.

Also this attribute not only checks for authentication but also can verify authorization. So you can use custom roles as well with Authorize attribute to restrict users to accessing specific views/actions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I tried using "SetAuthCookie" but I couldn't get past the [Authorize] filter. Having little knowledge of this, I'm not sure if I was doing something wrong, or if this isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out to me that I needed to look into cookies or existing membership providers, so I looked around in FormsAuthenticationTickets and rolled my own solution that I would love feedback on.

I ended up creating a new ticket when the login was successful with the FormsAuthenticationTicket class (see below).

```
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                user.Username,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                false,
                userData,
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            // Encrypt the ticket.
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            // Create the cookie.
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

Then I wrote a custom ActionFilter, so I could make my own method decorators (or whatever they're called).

```
namespace MyApp.Filters
{
    public class CustomLoginFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Retrieves the cookie that contains your custom FormsAuthenticationTicket.
            HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                // There's actually a cookie
                // Decrypts the FormsAuthenticationTicket that is held in the cookie's .Value property.
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                 if (authTicket != null && user != null && data == authTicket.UserData)
                 {
                     // Everything looks good
                     this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    //log bounceback - someone screwed with the cookie
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "Login" }, 
                        { "action", "Index" } 
                    });
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                //log bounceback - not logged in
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", "Login" }, 
                    { "action", "Index" } 
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll likely play with it more, but it seems to work fine for now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you don't need to add custom logic for redirection. FormsAuthentication already handles it internally if you specify it in the web.config under security section. Also the creating FormAuthenticationTicket is too custom when a single line of code can do the needful for you that I specified in my sample.

Comment: You are correct. Using the SetAuthCookie and GetAuthCookie do appear to do the job, but are they encrypted in the same way that I have done above? I'm interested in not only the cookie being present, but containing the correct data.

Comment: Use <httpCookies requireSSL="true"/> this will do the needful.